# Stuck at JWT verify (with Redis)

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, jwt

I am using Node.js plus a package called jwt-redis for creating and verifying authentication tokens in my API, this way I can then destroy them from redis db and logout.

I have already achieved the first part, token creation via jwtr.sign() method. The token is successfully created from a payload and a secret and then included in the response body, as well as a new key in redis.

Now, I am trying to implement a function to authenticate the token, which mainly gets the authorization header from the requests (it is printed correctly at console), connects the redis client (apparently OK too) and finally tries to verify it.

My code is as follows:

```
async function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
    // verify if user already exists
    const authHeader = req.header('Authorization')
    // console.log('autheader', authHeader)

    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1] //returns or undenifed or the token
    if (token == null) return res.status(401).json({ Error: 'Usuario no registrado' })
    console.log('token:' + token)

    const redis = require('redis');
    const JWTR =  require('jwt-redis').default;
    //ES6 import JWTR from 'jwt-redis';
    const redisClient = redis.createClient();
    const jwtr = new JWTR(redisClient)

    await redisClient.connect().then(function() {
        console.log("Redis plugged in.")
    })

    jwtr.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, function(err, user) {
        if(err) return res.status(401).json({ Error: 'Usuario no registrado' })
        console.log('user'+user)
        req.USER = user
        next()
    })
}
```

However, as said, it gets stucked at jwtr.verify(). Console prints both the token and the message "Redis plugged in", but nothing else happens. Application keeps running and postman call's button remains "Sending" until I force node to stop.

As that method returns a promise, so I have tried with both `then` and `await` with no success.

Any idea of what's happening here, guys?

I will really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation

> jwtr.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, [options]): Promise

you are handling that with callback

so I think that you have to modify your code in this way

```
jwtr.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET).then(user => {
   console.log('user'+user)
        req.USER = user
        next()
      }, err => {
       res.status(401).json({ Error: 'Usuario no registrado' })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried both with `then` and `await`, as the function returns a promise. I just copied and paste your code to try again but still not working...